# How to Group By and keep an specific column

Tags: sql, group-by

Having this table:

```
Number | Chapter |   Main  | Description  | value  
-------+---------+---------+--------------+--------  
1      |   1     |   false | description1 | 100  
1      |   1     |   false | description2 | 200  
1      |   1     |   true  | main desc.   | 0  
2      |   1     |   true  | main2        | 0
2      |   1     |   false | desc2        | 100
```

...

I need to Group By Number e Chapter and Sum(Value) but i need the description when Main = true (There is only 1 "Main" for each Chapter)

Expected Result:

```
Number | Chapter | Description | value  
-------+---------+-------------+--------  
1      |   1     | main desc.  | 300  
2      |   1     | main2       | 100
```

Thank You.

Comment: There is Number 1 and Number 2

Comment: How you get 200 as summed value ?

Comment: Sorry, my distraction, obviously is 100

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select number, chapter,
  max(case when main = 'true' then description end) description,
  sum(value) value
from tablename
group by number, chapter
```

If the column's `main` data type is `boolean` then change to:

```
max(case when main then description end)
```

Comment: Hey... that's MY answer! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` clause to find the description you want:

```
select
  number,
  chapter,
  max(case when main = 'true' then description end) as description,
  sum(value) as value
from t
group by number, chapter
```

Comment: Hey... that's MY answer! ;-)  just not yet published

Comment: @OtoShavadze LOL